# Запрос на выбор последнего результата по двум таблицам

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос, выбирающий последнюю запись по параметру `param3` из таблицы `table`:

```
'SELECT param FROM table WHERE param2 = ' . $param2. ' ORDER BY param3 DESC LIMIT 1'
```

Проблема в том, что параметр `param1` находится в одной таблице, а `param2` и `param3` - в другой, связанной с первой (соответствующие id). Каким образом можно модифицировать этот запрос для разных таблиц?

Comment: Свяжите таблице в запросе через `JOIN` http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/JOIN.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT param,  param3
FROM table 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table.id = table2.some_id and param2 = ' . $param2. ' 
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table.id = table3.some_id 
ORDER BY param3 DESC LIMIT 1
```

где то так

Comment: А как можно сохранить ID этой записи? Если после SELECT поставить `id`, то ругается.

Comment: Select table.id, table2.id, table3.id